# Continuously pulling variables off a website to use on Matlab?

Tags: matlab, web, auto-update

I am trying to continuously pull variables off this website (or a similar website)

> https://finance.google.com/finance?q=NYSE%3AGM&ei=-MUaWsnNCIKPUM3ngbAG

and use the variables in a Matlab code for some calculations. The variables i need are in the picture below.

I realize i could download a .txt from another site with the info but I need to update the variables every 10 secs or so, so that's not going to work.[image: GM stocks]

I would really appreciate any help in terms of where I can find resources to do this or something that will get me started. thank you!

Comment: Why couldn't you download the text file? Processing a file every 10s should not be that hard. Note that a web page is a (html) file too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code:

http://luminouslogic.com/matlab_stock_scripts/get_last_trade_google.m

Using `get_last_trade_google('GM')` will give you number 2, I guess you can figure out yourself how to get the other ones as well.

Comment: This actually works a lot better than I expected. THANK YOU!!